# How to find λ values from a basis solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I try this question many time but i stuck on this how to find λ values in the below question.

Find the differential Equation for which the given function form a basis solutions.

```
coshx , sinhx
```

Sample solution of this type question.
[**Solution**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0RHyHmdRczRaF9yUWpUTFRhb28)

Comment: Can you write $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ in terms of things which look like $e^{kx}$?  Can you combine these linearly to give things which look even more like a simple $e^{kx}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since:
$$
\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}\qquad\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}
$$
Thus $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ are solutions of the differential equation as well, since
$$
e^x=\cosh x+\sinh x\qquad e^{-x}=\cosh x-\sinh x
$$
So we have $(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)=\lambda^2-1$, thus:
$$
y''(x)-y(x)=0
$$